# is it necessary to close a stream in java 8 to run the intermediate operations and is close() a terminal operation

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Say I have a list on which I need to perform operations. If I chain those operations with streaming API, is it necessary to call a terminal operation or just stopping at intermediate operations can also be fine?

```
list.stream().filter(some filtering).peek(some change on the filtered items);

list.stream().filter(some filtering).peek(some change on the filtered items).close();
```

Changing this to

```
 list.stream().filter(some filtering).forEach(some change on the filtered items)
```

does what I want.

Is there any possibility of memory leaks in the first option ?
Why the peek() version doesn't work ??

Is close() a terminal operation and if it is, will this help me call setter on the filtered list items.

This question is

Comment: Have you *tried* the first example? Does it actually do something?

Comment: Short answer: it depends on the underlying source.

Comment: Furthermore, your example won't do anything, because you have not invoked a [terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), that means that the pipeline is not executed at all.

Comment: @luk2302:  not ran it till now. but expect it to run the setter method on the item in the source list. Will it not ?

Comment: ok, so in that I need to call close() in order to make it work or is close() not a terminal operation/.

Comment: @luk2302 well, *both* don’t do anything. But that’s a different topic…

Comment: @Holger if you put a SysOut call into the first snippet it will not print, if you put it into the second it will do -> "the first one does not do anything"

Comment: @luk2302 a stream without a terminal operation will not do anything, whether you append `close()` or not.